# how to return only the True values?

Tags: python, pandas, string, contains

I'm checking if a word is in the object in a dataframe series. Like this:

```
indicators['Indicator Name'].str.contains('population')
```

But when I run this command, my result is all values as true or false.
How can I print only the true values and show all of them? Since the
dataframe is huge.Like this:

```
ndicator Code
EG.CFT.ACCS.ZS        True
EG.ELC.ACCS.ZS        True
EG.ELC.ACCS.RU.ZS     True
EG.ELC.ACCS.UR.ZS     True
FX.OWN.TOTL.ZS        True
                     ...  
SG.VAW.NEGL.ZS       False
SG.VAW.REFU.ZS       False
SP.M15.2024.FE.ZS    False
SP.M18.2024.FE.ZS    False
SH.DYN.AIDS.FE.ZS     True
```

Comment: Please Try `indicators[indicators['Indicator Name'].str.contains('population')]`

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda expresion:

```
indicators[lambda x: x['Indicator Name'].str.contains('population')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on [MhDG7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3958878/mhdg7) answer, you might as well use the boolean series as an indexer, like:

```py
indicators[indicators['Indicator Name'].str.contains('population')]
```